# How is data passed from a SQL server to Joomla

Tags: sql, joomla

We sell a subscription to a software program and the data is stored in a SQL server.I want to grab a users expiration date and then display it on joomla. Our server guy said he uses REST. Can anyone help me understand how this data is passed from the SQL table to text on joomla? He also mentioned it has to pass through SSL but I am not certain where that ties in.

I am a complete novice and have no idea where to start when learning this material. Any resources to learn more would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: and why don;t you discuss it better with your server guy since he has the answer already? Am just curious?

Comment: very small company and I am usually written off because I am younger and have very little experience. I am eager to learn but his time is spent elsewhere.

Comment: Right now, I don't know how the environment is set up. Does the SQL server belongs to another application or with the Joomla? If it is with another application, you need a web service that talks on behalf of Joomla to your code, fetch the data and return it to Joomla. REST, SOAP, WCF, etc is what you will need

Comment: And you can also get a connection string to your SQL server database and retrieve data from Joomla if it is allowed. That might require PDO or `mssql_query`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to give you resources, just query google or youtube for that. There are so many out there, it's hard to point you to the right place.

From what you say it appears that your software information is running on a different server than joomla.

You can address this either with a direct connection to the database or by creating a dedicated software that will handle your requests on the "software info" server.

**Direct connection**
Usually remote access to a db server is disabled, and it's a good security measure.  You could however use mysql remote tables and limited accounts and access the remote database directly from a Joomla module or component.  This solution is pretty bad because it's dependant on the structure of the remote database.

**Writing software**
Here your Joomla extension would query a new software which you have to place on the database server. From what you write, the connection should be secure (https / ssl).

How you implement it (using REST, passing parameters with GET etc.) is really not significant, but there may be company standards and REST is nice and easy to understand.

So you would have to http get from your joomla extension:

(REST)

```
https://info-db-server-ip/license/130
```

(GET)

```
https://info-db-server-ip/license/index.php?userid=130
```

and the script would typically return a json encoded response which contains the license details.